# Clash between amsmath, atbegshi, and texpower packages?

Tags: amsmath, atbegshi

Consider this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{texpower}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\setbox0\hbox{\textbf{TEXT}}
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
\put(0,-\ht0){\usebox0}
}}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

`TEXT` appears in the upper left of the page. But as soon as you use `align` environment of `amsmath`, the `TEXT` disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{texpower}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\setbox0\hbox{\textbf{TEXT}}
\AtBeginShipout{%
\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
\put(0,-\ht0){\usebox0}
}}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\begin{align}
x&=1+2\\
&=2+1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use a scratch register such as `\box0` for non temporary purposes.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, I see. It was not actually my example. Someone sent it to me and I just panicked. Your suggestion fixes the problem. If you feel like making your comment into an answer, please do and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No packages are necessary to show the behavior.

Consider this Plain TeX example:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{Hello} % the same as \sbox0{Hello}
\copy0 % the same as \usebox0
{\box0}
\copy0
\bye
```

Once `\box0` is executed, the most recent incarnation is destroyed, so you see only *two* copies of “Hello” even if `\box0` is executed in a group.

It's true that `amsmath` doesn't manage temporary boxes in a very coherent way, but scratch registers should be used as soon as they are defined, not procrastinated to a future moment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{texpower}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newsavebox\vafabox
\sbox\vafabox{\textbf{TEXT}}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,-\ht\vafabox){\usebox\vafabox}%
}}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```